# Selenium webdriver usage plan?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Well I'm going to post some thoughts about a usage of Selenium NOT WAITING for response, but you're welcome if you want to give tips or tricks.

Need to start **automation testing** project to test: UI, functionality and performance (not sure but is very possible).

Want use Selenium as the base element of our testing BUT I'm a little bit confused about the Architecture that need to use, as this is my first time creating from scratch a bundle framework for automation testing need to know some stuff, for example...

What's the correct way to work with Selenium? I know about **Page Object** pattern but not sure on how to implement it, does it needs a real architecture like in a regular web app like MVC, or Data access layer or whatever?... I can't find any example of a complete framework testing ANY test-web-page..

What I mean?

Need to know how to implement correctly Selenium, any architecture, maybe using other tools like TestNg, Cucumber, or whatever...

other thing is to implement some kind of code repository (maybe git?) to work with members collaboration..

AND THEN...

what I need to know about WHO'S going to execute my automated test cases? is there a robot for it? need to investigate more about that and everything else :)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site. Your post is written more like a blog post, may I suggest editing it to sound like more of a question?

Comment: Reading the question I am not sure what exactly is your problem. Maybe you could do some reading and experimentation first, and then ask more specific questions? Good helpful questions (that also attracts good insightful answers) requires clear thinking from the original poster (it is not always easy, but writing down the problem in clear form  helps you to understand what are the important questions - you could just write first privately and then share the questions that take a shape, one by one in Stackoverflow). Stackoverflow is not a place for personal diary.

Comment: Often things seem uphill when you start..but things often fall into place "when you start".  Ok avoiding the philosophy.. To understand a bit of what systems fit where, here's something based on my understanding of things : http://niharikawhatsnext.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/test-automation-to-building-to-execution-to-scheduling-java/  And finally, get started

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are new to the testing world...and so, I'll explain basic concepts concerning what you asked.

*Selenium takes the browsers on your machine and runs them.  That's it, simply.*

Performance testing is possible, but I believe there are better tools for doing that.  I won't go into them here.

In order to write selenium code, there are really two parts...the **selector** and the **action**.   The selector tells WebDriver which element to perform the action on.  Because webpages change (but the actions may not), and because you may use an element twice in different places in your code, we separate the selector and the actions in our code.

The result of this is Page Objects.  In Java they look like this:

```
@FindBy(id = "logoffBtn")
WebElement logOffButton;
```

This says "In the HTML, there's an element that has an id of `logoffBtn`.  Next time I use `logOffButton`, find that element, and perform that action on it".

Now for the rest of your questions:

TestNG/Cucumber are testing frameworks.  They allow you to organize your tests, and make them flexible/powerful.

I'm not going into Git/Subversion.  They make it so different people can code on the same project, and are beasts of their own.

Finally, you *can* get your tests to run on different machines, but *somebody* has to own them and keep them running.  The common (and best) way to do this is with Selenium Grid.